# "vmware-installer: command not found" when trying to uninstall VMware Player

Tags: fedora, vmware

I am using fedora 16` and I need to uninstall VMware Player and VMware Workstation. I tried this:

```
[root@Feddy non-admin]# vmware-installer --uninstall-product vmware-player
bash: vmware-installer: command not found...
```

but the result says , `command not found`. In this case how do I uninstall VMware?

Comment: How did you install it in the first place?

Comment: @JosephR. I installed it a long time ago. I seriously don't remember the installation

Comment: try run vmware-uninstall.pl

Comment: @Salton the same result

Comment: check to see if there is any rpm package installed for this `rpm -qa | grep vmware`

Comment: Post the output of `echo -n "$PATH" | xargs -d : -I '{}' find '{}' -maxdepth 1 -executable -type f -printf '%P\n' | grep -i vmware`.

Comment: @Salton _xorg-x11-drv-vmware-11.0.3-6.fc16.i686_ the output

Comment: @EvanTeitelman `vmware-netcfg
vmware
vmware-tray
vmware-ping
vmware-unity-helper
vmware-acetool
vmware-gksu
vmware-vdiskmanager
vmware-remotemks
vmware-mount
vmware-modconfig
vmware-networks
vmware-authd
find: `/home/non-admin/.local/bin': No such file or directory
find: `/home/non-admin/bin': No such file or directory`

Comment: According to http://www.vmware.com/pdf/VMwarePlayerManual10.pdf , to uninstall you can type `rpm -qa | grep VM` and then `rpm -e VMwareXXXX`, where XXXX is numeric, representing the version you have installed.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tested yum or rpm as explained here:

https://ask.fedoraproject.org/question/8616/how-to-uninstall-those-programs/

e.g.

```
rpm -e VMware-Player
```

Should work if you installed it with yum or rpm. If you did not then I don't think there are any easy way.

Comment: Welcome to Unix and Linux! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score -2):

I do it with : vmware-installer -u vmware-player. - Debian 7 - 64bits
Then I could install vmware workstation 9 in test without any problem.

Comment: The OP clearly indicates that this command was unsuccessful.

Answer (score -2):

As root, the command "vmware-installer --uninstall-product=vmware-workstation"
uninstalled VMware-Workstation 9
Do not forget "="